# Django: Normalizing user-submitted model data for display in a template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I save user-submitted data in a model. I currently have template filters to normalize the data. For example:

```
Mcjunkin -> McJunkin
john and beth -> John & Beth
K.j. Johnson -> K.J. Johnson
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do this **without** using template filters every time I display these model fields?

I was thinking of perhaps having a `display_*` properties for the django fields I plan to display. Then instead of:

```
Name: {{ model_instance.name|normalize_name }}
```

I'll do:

```
Name: {{ model_instance.display_name }}
```

And it'll do the normalization of the field before displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bravo.  We do that also.

We have the "normalized-for-display" fields as properties.   As well as other things like derived calculations.